# How can I say if a URL is a post, page, or taxonomy archive?

Tags: permalinks, directory, google-chrome

I'm studying for SEO purposes how a few WordPress sites (that aren't mine) are organized, link structure architecture and so on.

Therefore I need to know if a specific URL of a website is a post, page, or a taxonomy archive.

Can I do that using Chrome Inspect tool? How?

If no, so any other way to get this information?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress sites usually use `body_class()`, which adds CSS classes to the `<body>` tag. If you inspect the body element itself, most sites will show you something like

`<body class="page-template page-template-tpl-events page-template-tpl-events-php page page-id-1168 page-parent page-child parent-pageid-378">`

You can tell from these classes that this is a Page, using a Page Template, it is a Parent, and it is also a Child. You'll see similar classes that tell you when you're on a Post, Archive, etc.